# Is it possible for someone to reverse my hash function if he has access to the assembly code?

Tags: hash, password-cracking

My application is written in C and the password is checked by obtaining the user's input and doing some string/math operation on each character, then the sum of each character ascii code is added up (to make it more difficult for crackers).

My question is: if a cracker has access to the EXE file and thus, can view the logic of my code from the assembly code, can they reverse the process and arrive at a password that can defeat the hash function?

I know that they will have to do some trial and error with millions of guesses, but can they arrive faster if they know how my hash function works?

Comment: sums are weak because 2+3 = 4+1 (aka a+d = b+c) and both would unlock the same lock. more keys unlocking the same lock means weaker lock security and faster guessing.

Answer (score 5):

From the brief description of your hash function, yes, it's likely.

It *shouldn't* be, if it's a good system (for more on this, see [Kerckhoff's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle)).  But when you roll your own crypto, you are almost certainly going to do it wrong (see [Schneier's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Schneier#Cryptography)).  Please don't.

If you use a [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), then knowing the source is irrelevant, as the algorithms are all public and proven to be secure.

Also, merely hashing a password is not a proper way to store it.  There is much more information on this topic on the third most-upvoted question on this site, [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/16960).

Comment: "proven to be secure" I think it'd be more accurate to say they _haven't_ been proven to be insecure. We have no proof that these algorithms are secure, we only know that a lot of really smart people have tried to break them and failed.

Comment: Good point.  Depending on which algorithm you're looking at and how you define "secure", some of them *are* proven secure, but from a real-world perspective you're absolutely right in that we just don't know about any critical issues.